# react-native: analytics().logPurchase() is throwing an error `unknown property 'items'.`

Tags: firebase, react-native

i have been following implementation guide to use firebase in our react-native application.

According to documentation: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics#logPurchase expects `PurchaseEventParameters`  https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics/purchaseeventparameters

which include `value`, `currency` as well as `items` which is a list of `Item` with mentioned parameters:

https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics/item

When using these parameters

```
const parameters = {
    "value": 64.55,
    "currency": "eur",
    "items": [
        {
            "item_category": "special_offer",
            "quantity": 1,
            "item_price": 64.55
        }
    ]
}

try {
        await analytics().logPurchase(parameters)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(' ~ error', error)
      }
```

we are getting an error `Error: firebase.analytics().logPurchaseEvent(*): unknown property 'items'.`

Now we are wondering, if documentation is outdated, or am i overseeing something important here?

- react-native 0.67.4
- @react-native-firebase 14.11.0

Thanks for any hint on this!

Comment: According to docs ```Item``` does not have a property called ```item_price```. Maybe try using ```price``` instead ?

Comment: @sushrut619 - thanks this was causing the misleading error. thanks for your good eyes. The `items` value unfortunately is still not received by firebase [Firebase missing items values][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVDci.png